# AWS S3 routing and domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have registered a domain name for my app. Let's say - "domain.com"
In AWS Route53 I have such entries at first:
domain.com NS entry
domain.com SOA entry

then I created A record "api.domain.com" to route traffic to my beanstalk load balancer

now I have created an S3 bucket to host a static landing page. My bucket is called "domain.com" so in Route53 I create A record "domain.com" for this bucket.

Now I tried to create A record for "www.domain.com" and route this requests to another A record - "domain.com", but this is not working. Gives me 404 error. How can I do this?

UPD: I have created another S3 bucket with name "www.domain.com" which redirects to "domain.com", but it looks like there should be a better way to achieve same behavior, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you did it, by creating a second bucked 'www' is the recommended approach - I agree it's awkward, but that is how it works - at least for now.

If you use cloudfront distribution in front of S3, you'll have a bit more flexibility on how the buckets (sources) are set up.